My sprite in unity is moving alot faster in the left direction and the up direction
I had thought that it was only in the left dirrection possibly due to the negative but seemingly not.
Here's the code:
  using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private float speed = 10;
        private float horizontalInput;
        private float verticalInput;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
        
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            {
                horizontalInput = -1;
            }
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            {
                horizontalInput = 1;
            }
              if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
            {
                horizontalInput = 0;
            }
              if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            {
                verticalInput = -1;
            }
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            {
                verticalInput = 1;
            }
                if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
            {
                verticalInput = 0;
            }
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            transform.Translate(Vector2.up * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime * speed);

            if(horizontalInput == 1 || horizontalInput == -1 && verticalInput == 1 || verticalInput == -1 )
            {
                speed = 5f;
            }
            else
            {
                speed = 10;
            }
        }
    }

Would anyone know how to fix this?
This has only started happening when i added code to correct the sprite speeding up in diagonal directions but its an important part of the code

if(horizontalInput == 1 || horizontalInput == -1 && verticalInput == 1 || verticalInput == -1 ) take a closer look at your conditions here. I think it is where your issue is

short answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/78561916/11913733
BUT
do this one to get out of this if maddness
float horizontalInput=Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

float verticalInput=Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

these two return a value between -1 and 1 and give you exactly what you want.
for movement instead of two translations do this.
in default setting this will be ASDW and arrow keys and controllers D-Pad but you can change it in settings. also you can use these two lines for a smoother feel
float horizontalInput=Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

float verticalInput=Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

then make the moveVector
vector2 moveVector=((Vector2.right * x)+(Vector2.up * y)).normalized *speed;

the "normalized" get the direction of vector and changes the magnitude of it to 1
then you multiply it by speed. this handles the diagonal movements.
then just use this line to do the move
transform.translate(moveVector);

GetAxis
GetAxisRaw
normalized



if( ( horizontalInput == 1 || horizontalInput == -1 ) && ( verticalInput == 1 || verticalInput == -1 ))



You want ONE and condition: IF horizontal input is NOT 0 AND Vertical input is NOT 0... then treat as diagonal
